# Как из Color вытащить цвета по отдельности?

Tags: java, android

Использую метод:

```
int clr = Color.argb(transp,red,green,blue);
```

А как сделать обратную процедуру, т.е. найти цвета и прозрачность из `clr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользоваться следующими методами:

- [`Color::alpha`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#alpha(int))
- [`Color::red`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#red(int))
- [`Color::green`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#green(int))
- [`Color::blue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#blue(int))

То есть вот так преобразуем компоненты в `int`:

```
int color = Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
```

А вот так из `int`'а получаем компоненты:

```
int alpha = Color.alpha(color)
int red = Color.red(color)
int green = Color.green(color)
int blue = Color.blue(color)
```